# How to measure the error of Finite Element approximation in satisfying the PDE?

Tags: finite-element, error-estimation, galerkin

In Galerkin methods, we seldom can measure the accuracy of an approximation by tracking the value of the residual. For example, take the wave equation:

$ u_{tt} = u_{xx}$, $(x,t) \in (0,L) \times (0,T)$ with approximation $u(x,t) \approx u_N(x,t) = \sum_{i=1}^N\phi_i(x)q_i(t)$

The residual for this approximation is defined as follows:

$R(x,t,N) =  \sum_{i=1}^N\phi_i''(x)q_i(t) - \phi_i(x)q_i''(t)$

for which we expect $R(x,t) = 0$ everywhere for $(x,t) \in (0,L) \times (0,T)$. The error metric in this case will be

$ \epsilon(N) = \int_0^T \int_0^L R(x,t,N)^2 dx dt $

However, in the Finite Element method, developing the above integral, the term $\phi_i''(x)$ persists. This term is not well defined in the FEM as we have $\phi_i(x)$ continuous and differentiable **once**. Is there a way to estimate the residual without necessitating $\phi_i''(x)$?

**My Work**

I understand that in the FEM, we are mostly concerned with the error metric $||u-u_N||$ rather than the error in residual. The other solution will be to compute $u_\infty$ (ie, $N$ very large, assuming convergence occurs) and use the error metric $||u_\infty-u_N||$ instead. However, in my case, as I increase $N$, I do not necessarily keep my initial conditions constant. My understanding is the $u_\infty$ is computed for given initial and boundary conditions while, for myself, only the boundary conditions are given and the initial conditions are **found** such that the solution is periodic $u_N(x,t) = u(x,t+T)$. So the initial conditions are not **given** per-se.  I would still prefer if there existed a way to compute the residual.

Answer (score 1):

The **residual error estimater** can help in your case.

Let $u_h\in V_h$ be the FE solution given at a time $t$ and assume you know $\frac{\partial^2 u_h}{\partial t^2}$ at the same time $t$ then you can define the residual at an element $T$ as:

\begin{align}
 \Delta u_h|_T - \frac{\partial^2 u_h}{\partial t^2}|_T
\end{align}

As you mentioned $\Delta u_h$ is not well defined since $\nabla u_h$ can have jumps at the edges of our elements in the mesh. But what we can still do is measure the violation of the continuity of $\nabla u_h$ at an edge $E=T_1\cap T_2$ by the normal-jump:

\begin{align}
 \left[\left|\frac{\partial u_h}{\partial n} \right|\right]:= \frac{\partial u_h}{\partial n_1}|_{T_1} + \frac{\partial u_h}{\partial n_2}|_{T_2}
\end{align}

By that we obtain the residual error estimator as:
\begin{align}
\eta^{res}(u_h,\frac{\partial^2 u_h}{\partial t^2})^2 := 
\sum_{T\in\mathcal{T}}\left[ h_T^2 ||\Delta u_h-\frac{\partial^2 u_h}{\partial t^2}||_{L_2(T)}^2 + \sum_{E:\text{ edge in } \partial T} h_E || \left[\left|\frac{\partial u_h}{\partial n} \right|\right] ||_{L_2(E)}^2\right]
\end{align}
where $h_T$ is the maximum distance between two points in element $T$ (longest edge for triangles) and $h_E$ respectively the longest distance between two points on the edge $E$ (edge lenght for triangles).
To see that the residual error estimator is a reasonable choice to recover the unknown error one can prove the following:

\begin{align}
c||u-u_h||_{V(\Omega)} \leq \eta^{res}(u_h,\frac{\partial^2 u_h}{\partial t^2}) \leq C||u-u_h||_{V(\Omega)}
\end{align}
where $c,C>0$ are positive constants and $u \in V(\Omega)$ is the exact solution of $\Delta u=\frac{\partial^2 u_h}{\partial t^2}$ at time $t$ in the Domain $\Omega$.
We usually call an error estimator **reliable** if the left inequality holds and **efficient** if the right inequality holds.
Since the residual error estimator is efficient and reliable, you have some guarantee, that it is at most a constant factor apart from your error $||u_h-u||_{V(\Omega)}$ and if your error blows up or goes to zero it will do the same.

Comment: This is not a good choice to measure the error. That's because if, for example, you use linear elements on triangles, $\Delta u_h=0$ on every triangle. In other words, you *should* have that the jump part of the residual more or less balances out $\partial_t^2 u_h$, but you don't see that because you applied the triangle inequality and measure them separately. As a consequence, your error estimate cannot be sharp.